# Is my algebraic space a scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks

Consider $\mathcal{M}_{1,1}$ over $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$.

I have an algebraic stack $\mathcal{M}$ finite etale over $\mathcal{M}_{1,1}$

I can prove that it is an algebraic space (essentially because all its "hidden fundamental groups" are trivial - ie, all geometric points of $\mathcal{M}$ have trivial 2-automorphism groups)

Must it be a scheme?

Comment: I don't know what your coy paranthetical remark means :P. But, a finite étale cover of $\mathcal{M}_{1,1}$ is DM. And, a DM stack is an algebraic space if and only if its inertia stack is trivial. Your paranthetical comment sounds a lot like you mean that the inertia stack is zero. So, no, I think you can probably show it's an algebraic space. You may then be able to argue some relative representability over $\mathbb{A}^1$, but I'd need to know more details. Hope this helps!

Comment: Would you care to comment? In other words, could you confirm that your parenthetical statement is that the inertia stack vanishes? Could you also give some more info on the  cover?

Comment: @AlexYoucis Yes it implies that it has trivial inertia stack, so it's an algebraic space. I'm just trying to prove that it's a scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is *yes*, and follows from two facts:

1. For an abelian variety $A/S$, and $\sigma\in Aut_S(X)$, if there is a point $s\in S$ such that $\sigma|_{A_s} = id$, then $\sigma = id$. (This is called "rigidity", and can be found in Mumford's *Geometric Invariant Theory*)
2. For a stack affine over $\mathcal{M}_{1,1}$, it is representable if and only if every object has no nontrivial automorphisms. (This is Scholie's result, theorem 4.7.0 in Katz/Mazur's Arithmetic Moduli of Elliptic Curves)

Statement (2) tells us that we just need to check that our objects have no automorphisms, and (1) tells us that it suffices to check this for elliptic curves over fields, so we're done.